# mysql-python installation error on Windows

Tags: python, mysql, django, installation, mysql-python

everybody. I am trying to get running with Django, but I'm stuck on the last process of installation - the mysql-python downloading and installation. This is the screenshot of Command Prompt:

[image: Command Prompt screenshot]

Can somebody tell me if this will affect the Django learning process at all (I know already that it comes with SQLite) and how to fix it if I have to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySql Python installation in windows, use [this](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python), which is 32/64 bit Windows binaries of mysql python. Installation is easy, just do this:

```
pip install some-package.whl
```

And if you use sqlite instead of mysql, it shouldn't hamper your progress of learning Django. If you want to see table structures and data from db, use [sqlite manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) or similar plugins to view them.

Comment: and should I remove the previously installed package, or can I just install the .whl one over/beside it?

Comment: Mysql Python wasn't installed in your system, so you will need to install the .whl one. other packages which are installed by pip directly should be fine.